# Optional(Error Domain=ContentBlockerErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)")

Tags: swift2, safari-extension, safari-content-blocker

I get the following error while load the json file with SFContentBlockerManager.reloadContentBlockerWithIdentifie

Optional(Error Domain=ContentBlockerErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)")

```
// This is my code to get attachment 

let documentDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
let jsonFileUrl =  documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("phantom.json")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: jsonFileUrl)
let attachment = NSItemProvider(item: data,typeIdentifier: kUTTypeJSON as String)
let item = NSExtensionItem()
item.attachments = [attachment]
context.completeRequestReturningItems([item], completionHandler: nil);

// Following code for SFContentBlockerManager
try! SFContentBlockerManager.reloadContentBlockerWithIdentifier("\(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier).PhantomBlocker", completionHandler: {(error) in print(error)})
```

Comment: It's rather a code snippet than an error. What's the error, and what's your specific question?

Comment: while loading safari content blocker from json file from document directory. SFContentBlockerManager throw error . Optional(Error Domain=ContentBlockerErrorDomain Code=1 “(null)”) ..please help i am new on IOS development

Comment: @SanjeetKumarNonia if you hav find the solution then please share with me becuase i got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem while running one of the open source project than after regular attempt i came to known that the app is using "Bundle Identifier" so i used that in the code and it started running.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have made a mistake in your `json` file. If you any type of error in the `json` file Xcode throws this error. There are some websites that validate you file. This should help you fix the issue.

*For example:*

1. http://jsonlint.com
2. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: I check it at both site as you suggested , it valid json file